# How to copy R8G8 Texture to UV part of NV12 ID3D11Texture2D?

Tags: shader, direct3d

Cuvid decode texture into NV12 format cuda memory, but I can't copy it using NV12 texture, so I want to copy it with a R8 Texture and a R8G8 Texture, then render the R8 and R8G8 texture into NV12 texture.

The D3D NV12 texture is composed of two planes: R8 and R8G8. According to the link provided ([https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/nvdec-decoded-frame-trying-a-zero-copy-to-nv12-d3d11-texture/123291), ↗](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/nvdec-decoded-frame-trying-a-zero-copy-to-nv12-d3d11-texture/123291),) this approach is feasible. The R8G8 texture is copyed from cuda decoded memory,

Currently, I have done some work, but I don't know how to write the vertex shader and pixel shader.

```
// Copy the data from the R8G8 plane to the U/V part of the NV12 Texture
// Create a RenderTargetView for the U/V part of the destination NV12 Texture
D3D11_RENDER_TARGET_VIEW_DESC rtDesc;
rtDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8_UNORM;
rtDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_RTV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
rtDesc.Texture2D.MipSlice = ; // Specify the mip slice level for the render target view
// D3D11 will map this render target view to the NV12 Chroma (U/V Interleave Plane)
device->CreateRenderTargetView(nv12Texture.Get(), &rtDesc, uvRTV.ReleaseAndGetAddressOf());

// Create a ShaderResourceView for the source R8G8 Texture
D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC srvDesc;
srvDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8_UNORM;
srvDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
srvDesc.Texture2D.MipLevels = 1;
srvDesc.Texture2D.MostDetailedMip = 0;
device->CreateShaderResourceView(r8g8texture.Get(), &srvDesc, uvSRV.ReleaseAndGetAddressOf());

// Render uvSRV to uvRTV
context_->OMSetRenderTargets(1, uvRTV.ReleaseAndGetAddressOf(), NULL);
context_->VSSetShader(vertexShader.Get(), NULL, 0);
context_->PSSetShader(uvPixelShader.Get(), NULL, 0);
context_->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, uvSRV.GetAddressOf());
context_->Draw(4, 0);
context_->Flush();
```

copy r8g8 texture to nv12' uv part